# while writing data in scylla table using pyspark.some time it write correctly sometime it did not write properly

Tags: pyspark, scylla

I am using three node cluster of scylla table i am reading and doing some changes on that df .and writing this new df again the same table.it showing writing completed but actually it do not updated that table data.used pyspark for it.

Comment: I think we'll need more information to give any meaningful answer. Scylla and Spark are both fairly mature products, so if writing a lot of data but nothing gets written was a bug, I'm sure everybody would have noticed this by now :-) So you're obviously doing something wrong, but it's hard to guess what given so little information about what you're doing.

Comment: For example i have 1 df.df1 it consit 3 columns col1,col2,col3.if i consider col 1 and lit value'1'in col3.and start writing this to table.it changes col3 0 to 1for some data .and else is on value '0' but in logs it is showing it writes successfully.instead of not changing 0 to 1.it is giving message successfully writes the data.but actually it writes 0 to 1 for few data nad remains are on 0.@NadavHar'El